# Stack overflow error bruteforcing a magic square. Any possible solution?

Tags: c, stack-overflow, backtracking, magic-square

Here my problem, for an exercise I need to generate a **magic square** by bruteforcing it in backtracking.

I thought it could be useful to allocate the matrix as a vector and a function that changes the coordinates. As you can imagine even with a 3x3 magic square it gave me a stack overflow problem.

Debugging it i discovered it happen, more or less, at half of the generating, more precisely where the function `chk_magic(int *m, int n)` call `change_coord(i, j, m, n);`.

Here it is the entire code, where I've signed the line that interrupt the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int chk_magic(int*, int);
void generate_magic(int*, int, int);
int change_coord(int, int, int*, int);

int back_f;

int main()
{
    int i, j, n=3, *m;
    //printf("Inserisci la dimensione del quadrato: ");
    //scanf("%d", &n);

    m=malloc(n*n*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<(n*n); i++)
    {
        m[i]=1;
    }
    printf("Generazione in corso (se la dimensione e' maggiore di 4 potrebbero volerci minuti)...\n");
    generate_magic(m, n, n*n-1);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("%3d ", change_coord(i, j, m, n));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

int chk_magic(int *m, int n)
{
    int i, j, magic_n, orizzontal_buffer, vertical_buffer, flag;
    flag=0;
    magic_n=n*(n*n + 1)/2;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        orizzontal_buffer=0;
        vertical_buffer=0;

        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            orizzontal_buffer+=change_coord(i, j, m, n); // <<-- HERE! HALP!
            vertical_buffer+=change_coord(j, i, m, n);
        }
        if(vertical_buffer!=magic_n || orizzontal_buffer!=magic_n)
        {
            flag=1;
            return flag;
        }
    }
    orizzontal_buffer=0;
    vertical_buffer=0;
    for(i=0, j=n-1; i<n; i++, j--)
    {
        orizzontal_buffer=change_coord(i, i, m, n);
        vertical_buffer=change_coord(i, j, m, n);
    }
    if(vertical_buffer!=magic_n || orizzontal_buffer!=magic_n)
        {
            flag=1;
        }

    return flag;
}

void generate_magic(int *m, int n, int pos)
{
    if(m[pos]<n*n)
    {
        m[pos]++;
        back_f=chk_magic(m, n);
        if(back_f==0)
        {
            return;
        }
        generate_magic(m, n, n*n-1);
        return;
    }
    if(m[pos]==n*n)
    {
        if(back_f==0)
        {
            return;
        }
        m[pos]=1;
        generate_magic(m, n, pos-1);
        return;
    }
    if(pos==-1)
    {
        return;
    }
    return;
}

int change_coord(int x, int y, int *m, int dim)
{
    return m[(x*dim)+y];
}
```

Googling around I discovered that for odd numbers there is an algorithm which generate it easily, but the problem persist for even numbers (furthermore my professor want it with bruteforce recursion).

Any possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is homework, so I'm not going to fix your code... however I'll do some analysis for you to show you the issue. FYI: You really should learn to use a debugger and trace your code.

---

Your big problem here is that your "recursive" logic just bounces back and forth between two blocks, there's no "lowest step" and thus you fill the buffer with too many function calls and get a stack overflow:

```
void generate_magic(int *m, int n, int pos)
{
    if(m[pos]<n*n)
    {
        m[pos]++;
        back_f=chk_magic(m, n);
        if(back_f==0)
        {
            return;
        }
        generate_magic(m, n, n*n-1);  <--- 'Recursive' step
```

So when you call this function you have `m* == your memory block`, `n == 3` and `pos == 8` (3*3-1).

I put "recursive" in quotes, because you're not doing a decremental step, this code runs each time calling `generate_magic()` with the same parameters over and over again (`n` is always 3, `pos` is always 8)

After a few iterations `m[pos]` will increment from 1 up to 9, now that if check fails and we jump down to the next block:

```
if(m[pos]==n*n)
{
    if(back_f==0)
    {
        return;
    }
    m[pos]=1;
    generate_magic(m, n, pos-1);  <- 'Recursive' step
```

So now we enter the code set m[pos] from the previous value (9) back to the value we started with (1) then we do the "recursive" step, calling `generate_magic()` with the values (`n==3`, `pos=7`, and `m[pos]==1`)

Ok, so we've started all over again with different values this time, right? First time we had:

`n == 3` and `pos == 8`

Now we have:
 
`n == 3` and `pos == 7`

Oops, but what happens when we hit that first "recursive" call again?

```
generate_magic(m, n, n*n-1);
```

That's going to reset our next entry to:

`n == 3` and `pos == 8`

This is getting nowhere fast. Sooner or later all these function/parameter pushes on the stack will kill us because we're getting into an infinite loop.

---

Side note:

```
malloc(n*n*sizeof(int*));
```

You wanted `sizeof(int)`, not `sizeof(int*)` since you're string `int`s in your matrix, not pointers to `int`s.

Comment: I thank you, but I still don't have any other idea! 
The hint for the exercise is:

_The recursive function which have to find the square have to try all the possible matrices in the interval [1, N^2]. A the final step you just have to verify if the matrix is a magic square. If yes stop the recursion and print the matrix. Furthermore you may use an auxiliary vector for "marking" the values used, so that the function won't use more than once a combination. That implies that, if "exiting" from the recursion, it's needed a backtrack to "unmark" those values, before using the next value_

Comment: Sorry for the bad translation, but I haven't got it.
By the way, I understood what you wrote above.

Comment: @LambertoBasti - I'd have to think about it for a bit to come up with an algorithm... this task would be much easier with an iterative function, but I suggest you look at some simple recursive examples. The reason your code doesn't work is you have two completing recursive steps in the same function... the idea of recursion is that you find a simple task in a more complex one. Think about the fact that your recursive function will run the same code over and over again, so write our what you're trying to do on paper. You want to make a magic square, so you need element 1, 2, & 3 to add to a

Comment: number, then you want 4, 5, & 6 to add to the same number, then 7, 8 , 9 to the same number, etc for 1, 4, & 7… So look for commonality in this task.

Comment: You made me think at something like [this](http://codepad.org/8rJ4zajv), but is still don't work. Following all the changes on the matrix while debugging made me see that the new `void generate_magic_no_recursion(int *m, int n)` produce all the possible matrices, but the `chk_magic` always flag it as non magic. I'm trying to understand why