# Algorithm: maximizing the output of a pastry shop. How to without the greedy algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm

Here the problem:

> you got a list of ingredients (assuming their value unitary) with
> their respective quantities, and a list of products.  Each product got
> a price and the recipe which contain the needed ingredients an their
> quantities.
>
> You need is to maximize the total proceeds from those products with
> the given ingredients.

The first thing blowing up in my mind is **to create a price/(n° needed items) ratio and start creating the products with the highest ratio**. I know that this is some kind of greedy algorithm (if I'm not wrong) and not always lead to the best solution but I had no other implementable ideas.

**Another way may be to brute-force all the possibilities**, but I'm not able to realize how I can implement it; I'm not so familiar with the brute-forcing. My first brute-force algorithm was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419584/stack-overflow-error-bruteforcing-a-magic-square-any-possible-solution), but it was easy because it was with numbers and, furthermore, the element that comes after is not precluded by the previous elements.

Here the things are different, because **the next element is a function of the available ingredients, whom are influenced from the previous products**, and so on.

Have you any hint? This is some kind of homework, so I prefer not a direct solution, but something to start from!

---

The language I have to use is ***C***

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try something in your language of choice, and post that.

Comment: step 1: reduce to a known problem; step 2: translate the solution to that known problem into your specific context. Good luck!

Comment: @Jhon - The language is C, but i got no ideas, so I didn't write nothing! I don't know where to start :(

Comment: Why not figure out a way to prioritize/rank different recipes based on their ingredients, cost of ingredients, number of ingredients available, and total profit for that recipe? (IE higher profit recipes get higher priority, make as many of those as you can, then move to the next one. You might also want to take into account the number of items you can actually make, so a $5 profit recipe that only makes one doesn't outrank a $1 recipe that you can make 10 of)  Not a perfect solution, but workable.

Comment: @Dazedy - The cost of the ingredients is unitary, so that cannot help me, and yes, prioritizing was one of my first ideas, but after the one i wrote, what else? 
I also thought of something like prioritizing with the most used ingredients and so on.
Unfortunately the exercise asks for the higher possible profit, so no way :(

Comment: Unitary as in, it's assumed they're all of equal value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the CPU cycles to do it (and efficiency doesn't matter), brute force is probably the best way to go, because it's the simplest and also guaranteed to always (eventually) find the best answer.

Probably the first thing to do is figure out how to enumerate your options -- i.e. come up with a way to list all the different possible combinations of pastries you could make with the given ingredients.  Don't worry about prices at first.

As a (contrived) example, with a cup of milk and a dozen eggs and some flour and sugar, I could make:

- 12 brownies
- 11 brownies and 1 cookie
- 10 brownies and 2 cookies
- [...]
- 1 brownie and 11 cookies
- 12 cookies

Then once you have that list, you can iterate over the list, calculate how much money you would make on each option, and choose the one that makes the most money.

As far as generating the list of options goes, I would start by calculating how many cookies you could make if you were to make only cookies; then how many brownies you could make if you were to make only brownies, and so on.  That will give you an absolute upper bound on how many of each item you ever need to consider.  Then you can just consider every combination of items with per-type-numbers less than or equal to that bound, and throw out any combinations that turn out to require more ingredients than you have on hand.  This would be really inefficient and slow, of course, but it would work.

Comment: Reasonable example, assuming that efficiency isn't a requirement for the project, which it doesn't sounds like it is. Pretty much the kind of program you run once in the morning to figure out what to make.

Comment: Seems the solutions required! I'l start writing some lines!

Answer (score 5):

I would first try looking at this as a [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem; there are algorithms available to solve them efficiently.

If your problem can't accept a fractional number of items, then it is actually an [integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) problem.  There are algorithms available to solve these as well, but in general it can be difficult (as in time-consuming) to solve large integer programming problems exactly.

Note that a linear programming solution may be a good first approximation to an integer programming solution, e.g. if your production quantities are large.

Comment: Yeah I was about to post - this seems like linear programming 101

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledges are not so far to completely understand whay you wrote, by the way I will inform about those two branches